# How to fix Datatables css not applying on Datatables?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've been trying to include a Datatable from datatables.net, it works fine, the paging, sorting and search bar work fine but the datatables css file doesn't apply on the Datatable (it looks old and unstylish, not the way it looks like in datatables.net) I'm using tabler.io as a template for my webapp and it uses Bootstrap 4.3.1.

these are the css and js files i'm using :

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> //bootstrap 4.3.1
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Datatables Theme Creator](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator) to add custom styling.

1. Choose your styling options at the top of the page
2. Click "Create Stylesheet"
3. Click on the "CSS" tab at the bottom of the page and copy and paste it into your CSS file.

I have found the theme creator somewhat annoying to use though. What I found more useful was the CSS that it outputted that you copy and paste into your CSS file, can be manipulated to your specific needs.

Theres a lot of CSS outputted though so this can be a problem. I suggest putting it at the bottom of your CSS file so it doesn't get in the way of your other CSS with 350+ lines of stylings.

Comment: I don't get it, do i copy it to the bottom of the bootstrap css file? if you're talking about app.css then that's bootstrap local file.

Comment: Which .css file do you use to apply normal styling to your page? Say if you wanted to make some text bigger or align it to the centre of the page? It looks like it might be css/app.css'?

Comment: I usually load bootstrap via CDN (like you have done with datatables) and have a separate .css file (like your app.css) for my own css styling. For you it would look like:      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: The comment keep cutting out the full CDN but you can find it here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Sorry but what i meant is app.css in my project contains bootstrap, i'm using a UI template (tabler) which apparently keeps bootstrap local, app.css isn't my custom css file where i keep my custom stylings.

Comment: Ah right. You might have to find out how to apply your custom css whilst using tabler as it sounds like you don't have a custom css file? I'm afraid I haven't used tabler before. I suspect that you could still use the method in the answer and copying and pasting the CSS into your app.css file and it should still work (despite it looking weird with bootstrap also inside) but I've not tried it before.

Comment: I'm on this problem for hours. Haven't figured out yet?